# Consuming an XML web service in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I'm attempting to use a web service from this site: http://www.averittexpress.com/services/technology/webservices.html

The web service I'm trying to use is the very first one on the page: http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService

I've never consumed a web service before, so I'm not sure where to start. I've done searches, but all the articles and blog posts that come up are nearly 10 years old.

I tried adding a web reference to my project in Visual Studio and entering the service url, but I just got an error.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

Error message:

*The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
There was an error downloading 'http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.*

**EDIT 2:**

I used http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService?WSDL when adding a web reference. XML loaded in the preview window, but I still received these errors:

*The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService/TransitTimeService_schema1.xsd'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.*

And these lines are highlighted red in the preview window:

```
<definitions name="TransitTimeService"
    targetNamespace="http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" <!-- highlighted red -->
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" <!-- highlighted red -->
    xmlns:tns="http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService" <!-- highlighted red -->
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"> <!-- highlighted red -->
```

Comment: hi steven , what is the error you are getting when you are adding as a service reference.

Comment: Sorry, should've included the error in the first place. I edited my original post, it's in there now.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you gave has all the info

http://www.averittexpress.com/services/technology/webservices.html

Including the *correct* location of the WSDL

http://www.averittexpress.com/services/technology/wsdl/TransitTimeService.wsdl

The location of the schema file is also there its

http://www.averittexpress.com/services/technology/wsdl/TransitTimeService_schema1.xsd

Comment: When I tried adding a web reference, it was trying to find http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService/TransitTimeService_schema1.xsd, but couldn't find it. Is there a way to change the path to the schema for the web reference?

Comment: Looks like the wsdl has some bad references. I haven't tried this but you can try and download the xml (via a web browser) fix the links and take the instruction Juliet gave. But use a modified version. Otherwise you're going to have to use the phone or email contacts from the first page

Answer (score 0):

Use the following URL: http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService?WSDL

You can either import the WSDL as a web reference, or you can create the proxy by hand by doing the following:

- Open a Visual Studio command prompt (Start > Visual Studio 2010 > Visual Studio Command Prompt)
- `cd` to your code directory
- `svcutil http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService?WSDL`, should generate a client proxy called TransitTimeService.cs or something similar.
- See the [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) documentation for customizing the output file to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Juliet. I used http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService?WSDL when creating the web reference. I got a little further, but I'm still getting errors. I edited my original post to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you're wanting to create a web or service reference, you will need the WSDL for the web service.  For most standard web services, you can get to the service's WSDL by appending a `?wsdl` to the end of the base URL like this:

http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService?wsdl

In this case, the URL above redirects to this:

http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService/TransitTimeService.wsdl

You should be able to use either of these to generate a web or service reference.  However, in this particular case, there is a file referenced in the TransitTimeService.wsdl that does not seem to exist on that server:  TransitTimeService_schema1.xsd.  When I tried to create a service reference for that WSDL, I got a 404 saying that the schema file does not exist.  The URL below is where the schema should be, but it's not there, so you may not be able to easily generate a reference for this service.

http://webservices.averittexpress.com/TransitTimeService/TransitTimeService_schema1.xsd

Comment: Thanks Andy, I guess I'll have to contact the company about that.